# Why adding white space makes my regex wrong?

Tags: java, regex

```
(^\s*\d+\)(.*) | ) | (^\s*Q\d+\.\s*(.*))
```

The above regex is not matching `Q1. qeqwewqeqeq qerqer`

But If I remove white space before and after `|`

```
(^\s*\d+\)(.*) | )|(^\s*Q\d+\.\s*(.*))
```

It matches my string.

What does white space mean? Is it equal to `\s`? It affects my readability.

Comment: Literal whitespace is meaningful for regex. Prepend the pattern with `(?x)` if you need to make it "formatting" whitespace.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks. Meaningful? Is it equal to `\s`?

Comment: No, `\s` matches more than a space, like tabs, newlines, CR...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a regex pattern, spaces are meaningful atoms that match spaces. If you need to format your pattern with spaces and tabs and newlines - with *whitespace* that will not be accounted for by the regex engine - you may use the `(?x)` modifier, or the [`Pattern.COMMENTS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#COMMENTS) flag.

Then, to match a literal space in such a pattern with `(?x)` option, you need to escape spaces to match literal spaces. Or, you may consider matching any whitespace with `\s`:

```
\s  A whitespace character: [ \t\n\x0B\f\r]
```

Note that in case you add `(?U)` modifier, [`Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS) flag, `\s` will match all Unicode whitespace (like `[\p{Zs}\t\r\n]`).

Comment: Done  Thanks :) :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, whitespace affects your regex. No, it is not equivalent to `\s`.

The `\s` [*shorthand character class*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) is equivalent to the character class `[ \t\r\n\f]` - i.e. a character class that will match any whitespace character. So, while your formatting spaces are *included* in `\s`, they are not *equivalent* to it.

As has been said in the comments, literal whitespace is important in regexes. In fact, I believe it's causing an error in your first alternate (the sub-pattern `(^\s*\d+\)(.*) | )`).

If I'm reading the intent of that sub-pattern right, it's supposed to match text of the form

```
2) some_text
```

But it will:

1. Only match this text if it's followed by a space
2. Also match a single literal space

A better way to construct this sub-pattern would be `(^\s*\d+\)(.*))`, disposing of the end space and the alternation altogether. Furthermore, in order to improve readability, we can do this:

```
(^\s*(?:Q\d+\.|\d+\))\s*(.*))
```

Which only alternates on the question number format, rather than the whole pattern.

[Demo on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/1JLk90/1)

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for additional tips

Answer (score 2):

The contents of a regex are 100% applicable to the determination of whether or not an input matches.  Your imagination does not change regex processing.

The regex "\dignore this part\d" will not match the input "12" but will match the input "1ignore this part2".  No matter how much in imagine the "ignore this part" will be skipped, it is still part of the regular expression.

In your case, the extra spaces are your form of "ignore this part".